# Get declared child classes of a certain abstract class, but without instantiating them

Tags: php, class, reflection

Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
$classes = get_declared_classes();
$models = array();

foreach($classes as $class){
  $class = new \ReflectionClass($class);
  if($class->isSubclassOf('\\App\\Model'))
    $models[] = $class;
}
```

But as you see I'm creating a reflection object for each class, in order to find out which one is a child of my "model" class.

Is there a faster way to search for my child classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
is_subclass_of($class, '\\App\\Model', true); // or is_a()
```

Pop last argument if you get notices/warnings. The 3rd one says 1st argument is a string and should not be directly rejected *(function expects objects by default)*.

```
is_subclass_of($class, '\\App\\Model'); // or is_a()
```

Works for me!

Comment: `Warning: is_subclass_of() expects exactly 2 parameters, 3 given` .. I know its not what the doc says .....

Comment: I got PHP 5.3. http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-subclass-of.php Read the manual. 3 arguments. Pop last for older PHP.

Comment: I know what the doc says ..... am testing it on `PHP 5.3` .. Just saying its a new interesting error ...

Comment: Pop last argument. The 3rd one says 1st argument is a string and should not be directly rejected.

Comment: @Alex Sure it is. You skip an instantiation :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
foreach($classes as $class){
  if($class->is_Subclass_Of($class, '\\App\\Model', true))
    $models[] = $class;
}
```

or you can see [is_subclass_of php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-subclass-of.php)

Comment: You meant is_subclass_of($class, '\\App\\Model', true);?